# How to get Data from SAML Response using XSL Transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am trying to enable SAML Single-Sign-On Service on our enterprise Software using Azure AD as Identity Provider(IdP from now on). 
Keep getting 
HTTP ERROR: 500
Problem accessing .../myhost/client/SAML2/POST. Reason:

```
Cannot create authentication master data from: ...
```

```
<root>
  <party isgroup="0" isactive="1" isvisible="1" issystem="0" auth_extern="2" auth_standard="0" sync_extern="0" login="[NameID]" count_invalid_logins="0" display_name="[USER DISPLAY NAME]" name="[USER_LAST_NAME]" firstname="USER_FIRST_NAME" locale="[LANG_CODE]" email="[USER_EMAIL]" main_role="[ROLE]" main_domain="[CENSHARE_DOMAIN]" main_domain2="[CENSHARE_2ND_DOMAIN]" expiry_date="2019-11-29T19:38:55.528Z">
    <party_role role="userrole" domain="[CENSHARE_DOMAIN]" domain2="[CENSHARE_2ND_DOMAIN]" enabled="1"/>
  </party>
</root>
```

Since I am getting a response from my IdP, seems that I am not mapping the data correctly. It's been bothering me for days and I can't find the solution. 
SAML Response from AAD:

```
<Assertion ID="_787xe00" IssueInstant="2019-10-30T19:50:32.912Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
  <Issuer>
    https://sts.windows.net/178x117/
  </Issuer>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
      <Reference URI="#_7877x7e00">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <DigestValue>
          Sx7lGM=
        </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>
   ca1+K4aeUV07UJsA9TjChAaj6rKAsYU92ZsRWrlwvbeMpGXptyQBXfUJII1azvqNgtv4Cdqom+hZhdblablaCDmQ==
    </SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>
          blablaP9dHmv+Mzhe9i5wjs
        </X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
  <Subject>
    <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">
      boxx@xxxx.at //DATA THAT I WANT TO CATCH FOR STARTERS
    </NameID>
    <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
      <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_46e00b1831xbb0a43a" NotOnOrAfter="2019-10-30T19:55:32.912Z" Recipient="https://myhost/client/SAML2/POST"/>
    </SubjectConfirmation>
  </Subject>
  <Conditions NotBefore="2019-10-30T19:45:32.896Z" NotOnOrAfter="2019-10-30T20:50:32.896Z">
    <AudienceRestriction>
      <Audience>
        https://myhost/client/client
      </Audience>
    </AudienceRestriction>
  </Conditions>
  <AttributeStatement>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid">
      <AttributeValue>
        1784x931fe8117
      </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier">
      <AttributeValue>
        3e33xaf0
      </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname">
      <AttributeValue>
        Borislav
      </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider">
      <AttributeValue>
        https://sts.windows.net/1784xfe8117/
      </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences">
      <AttributeValue>
        http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/password
      </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname">
      <AttributeValue>
        Borislav
      </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname">
      <AttributeValue>
        M
      </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
      <AttributeValue>
        borisxxxx@xxxxxx.at
      </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
      <AttributeValue>
        borisxxxxx@xxxxx.at
      </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
  </AttributeStatement>
  <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2019-10-30T16:29:23.770Z" SessionIndex="_7877x00">
    <AuthnContext>
      <AuthnContextClassRef>
        urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password
      </AuthnContextClassRef>
    </AuthnContext>
  </AuthnStatement>
</Assertion>
```

And this is my XSL Transformation

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"                 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"                 
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                 
                xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"                 
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all" >   
 <xsl:template match="saml:Assertion">
         //**** Do i need some params here to fetch the data? ****     
  <root>       
   <party isgroup="0" 
          isactive="1" 
          isvisible="1" 
          issystem="0"              
          auth_extern="2" 
          auth_standard="0" 
          sync_extern="0"              
          login="[USER NAMEID]" ---!!!!-- think that this is problematic
          count_invalid_logins="0"              
          display_name="[USER DISPLAY NAME]" 
          name="[USER_LAST_NAME]"
          firstname="USER_FIRST_NAME" 
          locale="[LANG_CODE]"
          email="[USER_EMAIL]"               
          main_role="[ROLE]" 
          main_domain="[OUR_DOMAIN]" main_domain2="[OUR_2ND_DOMAIN]">         
     <xsl:attribute name="expiry_date"                        
                    select="xs:dateTime(current-dateTime()) 
                            + xs:dayTimeDuration('P30D')"/>         
     <party_role role="userrole" 
                 domain="[OUR_DOMAIN]" 
                 domain2="[OUR_2ND_DOMAIN]" 
                 enabled="1"/>       
    </party>     
  </root>      
 </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What am I doing wrong?
I changed the data for obvious reasons :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I got no answer I did my best to find out on my own :)

The answer is quite simple: In the snippet right after the template match we need to add variables according to our needs, fetch the data with XPath expression and then use the same variables down in the transformation. Example:

```
<xsl:variable name="user-name-id" select="saml:Subject/saml:NameID"/>
```

and then call it just like any other variable:

```
login="{$user-name-id}"
```

We just need to follow the path of the XML Structure from our SAML Assertion.